# Make Gnome Hot Corner Delay

Tags: gnome

Is there any way to make the top left gnome hot corner delay for 1s before triggering? It's a very useful feature, but I end up accidentally touching the corner (esp when reaching for the file button), so I was wondering if I could lessen the sensitivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also another extension called "Activities Configurator", which can be used to **change the corner treshold**, fully **disable the hot corner**, or **switch it to the top right** of the screen.

This extension can also do much more, like adding an icon next to the Activities button, changing the text of the Activities button, or fully removing it.

---

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/358/activities-configurator/

---

Answer (score 0):

[No Top Left Hot Corner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/)

This extension disables the top left hot corners. You can still click on Activities or press the dedicated key (generally <kbd>Super</kbd> key to reach the overview.

This doesn't do exactly what you want but it should prevent from accidental Hot Corner triggers

---

[How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions)